# How do I block on ToObservable with a List<>?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am trying on RX for the first time and I have a couple questions.

1) Is there a better way to accomplish the Async of my collection?

2) I need to block on the thread until all Async Tasks are complete, how do I do that?

```
class Program
{

    internal class MyClass
    {
        private readonly List<int> _myData = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

        private readonly Random random = new Random();

        public int DoSomething(int j)
        {
            int i = random.Next(j * 1000) - (j * 200);
            i = i < 0 ? 1000 : i;
            Thread.Sleep(i);
            Console.WriteLine(j);
            return j;
        }

        public IObservable<int> DoSomethingAsync(int j)
        {
            return Observable.CreateWithDisposable<int>(
                o => Observable.ToAsync<int, int>(DoSomething)(j).Subscribe(o)
                );
        }

        public void CreateTasks()
        {
            _myData.ToObservable(Scheduler.NewThread).Subscribe(
            onNext: (i) => DoSomethingAsync(i).Subscribe(),
            onCompleted: () => Console.WriteLine("Completed")
                );
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass test = new MyClass();

        test.CreateTasks();

        Console.ReadKey(); 
    } 
}
```

(Note: I know I could have used Observable.Range for my list of Int but my list is not of type Int in the real program).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably try

```
public void CreateTasks()                
{                       
    _myData.ToObservable(Scheduler.NewThread)
        .SelectMany(i => Observable.Start(() => DoSomething(i)))
        .Subscribe(j => Console.WriteLine("j is {0}", j), 
                  () => Console.WriteLine("Completed"));       
}
```

So firstly I've changed the DoSomethingAsync so that it uses `Observable.Start`. Observable.Start will run the `DoSomething` method asyncronously and return the value through `IObservable.OnNext` when the method completes.

Then the CreateTasks method runs over each item in the collection as it did before, but feeds each value into a `SelectMany` which continues  with a call the DoSomethingAsync method.  The result is, that you'll then recieve an `OnNext` for each completed call to DoSomethingAsync and an `OnComplete` when they are all complete.

Comment: Cool, this works great, how would I do this with a Hot observable (I notice in my sample it works fine with out the Defer)?

Comment: @MrJavaGuy - My bad...  not sure, but i think at work I have an older version version where Start returns a hot observable. Just tested a more recent version and it is returning a Cold observable. I think now it'd be cleaner to remove DoSomethingAsync altogether. See latest edit.